# Execute JS while scrolling on Chrome mobile

Tags: javascript, android, google-chrome, mobile, scroll

If I understand correctly, Chrome mobile stops JS code execution while scrolling in order to improve scrolling performance. I was wondering if it is possible to have my code keep running while scrolling?

Answer (score 1):

Most mobile browsers just don't fire the **onscroll** event while scrolling.

There doesn't seem to be a generic solution to it either. 
You can check [this](http://tjvantoll.com/2012/08/19/onscroll-event-issues-on-mobile-browsers/) blog article with some test examples.